# Apache Camel with database query in Java DSL

Tags: java, dsl

I'm currently trying to import some data from Oracle to ElasticSearch (in JSON format) using Apache Camel. I'm totally new on this framework, so I was thinking that you might help with it !

The problem is that my routeBuilder take the data from my table Entreprise `.setBody(constant("select * from entreprise")).to("jdbc:myDataSource")` and I get something like that : {id=1231, test=hello}, so I put it in a custom processor which add the quotes. I think this is quite ugly to modify a String because of the integers, booleans, arrays that shouldn't be between quotes, so I'd rather use an Object like a HashMap.

I've tried the apache-sql example which use Spring to create his route :

```
<route id="processOrder-route">
  <from uri="sql:{{sql.selectOrder}}?consumer.onConsume={{sql.markOrder}}"/>
  <to uri="bean:orderBean?method=processOrder"/>
  <log message="${body}"/>
</route>
```

and finally get the informations into a HashMap :

```
 public String processOrder(Map<String, Object> data) {
    return "Processed order id " + data.get("id") + " item " + data.get("item") + " of " + data.get("amount") + " copies of " + data.get("description");
}
```

So my main question his : **what is the equivalent to this route in Java DSL which could return a HashMap or something like that ?**

Here is my code :

```
public class MainApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:alexis/alexis@localhost:1521:xe";
    System.out.println("Setting up data source.");
    DataSource dataSource = setupDataSource(url);
    System.out.println("Done.");

    SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry() ;
    reg.put("myDataSource", dataSource);

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);
    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    context.addRoutes(new MainApp().new MyRouteBuilder());
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(3000); 
    context.stop();
  }

  class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() {
        Processor proc = new ConvertToJSON();
        String dst = "C:/Users/**/Desktop/Workspace_sts/democamelJava/data";
        from("timer://foo?period=2s")
        .setBody(constant("select * from entreprise"))
        .to("jdbc:myDataSource").split(body()).process(proc)
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("file://" + dst);
        //.to("elasticsearch://localhost:9200?operation=INDEX&indexName=twitter&indexType=tweet");
    }
}
```

Thank you for every answer !

Comment: I think I found something : from("sql:select * from entreprise?dataSource=myDataSource").bean(new BeanProcessor(), "processOrder").to("file://" + dst); But it seems that the property dataSource is not recognized..

Comment: My version of apache-camel was under 2.11, that's why ! Now it works, I have my HashMap !